# class another class method in another class in php

Tags: php, pdo

I created a class named function and calling function method in another class named test. But it shows me an error -

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function

my function class's object name is `$obj = new functions();`

when i call user method which is written in function class from test class I am getting an error.

Comment: Can you share your code please, clearly you aren't initializing your other class ?

Comment: you can't its a bad practice.

Comment: you can set class name "className" and function name is "functionName"

Comment: Below is my function class  written in function.php

`class functions

{
function users(){

$users = "Demo User";
return $user;
}

}
$obj = new functions();`



Below is my test class

  `include('../function.php');

 $test_class = new test;

 class test
 {
  
  public function __construct()
  {
  $detail = $obj->users();
  }
 
 }`

Comment: Can you add this code to your post and not post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class className {
        function users(){
         $users = "Demo User"; return $user;
         }
  } 
 $obj = new functions();
```

you mean this:

Comment: yes this is function class that is written same as it is in function.php page now how to call this users method in test class constructor?

Answer (score 0):

you can extends

```
class className extends test{
   function __construct(){
```

here you add

}

```
    }
```

Comment: i tried this but i give me an error failed to call member function